# Creating boxplot based on some conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

Data given are a sample of cholesterol levels taken from 24 hospital employees who were on a standard American diet and who agreed to adopt a vegetarian diet for 1 month. Serum-cholesterol measurements were made before adopting the diet and 1 month after.

```
   Subject Before After Difference
1        1    195   146         49
2        2    145   155        -10
3        3    205   178         27
4        4    159   146         13
5        5    244   208         36
6        6    166   147         19
7        7    250   202         48
8        8    236   215         21
9        9    192   184          8
10      10    224   208         16
11      11    238   206         32
12      12    197   169         28
13      13    169   182        -13
14      14    158   127         31
15      15    151   149          2
16      16    197   178         19
17      17    180   161         19
18      18    222   187         35
19      19    168   176         -8
20      20    168   145         23
21      21    167   154         13
22      22    161   153          8
23      23    178   137         41
24      24    137   125         12
```

Now here is the question I am trying to answer. Some investigators believe that the effects of diet
on cholesterol are more evident in people with high rather than low cholesterol levels. If you split the data  according to whether baseline cholesterol is above or below the median, can you comment descriptively on this issue?
Now, I am thinking of creating boxplot based on two categories here. I wish to use `dplyr` for data manipulation here. So, I will create a new column based on if `Before` is less than or greater than median of `Before`. So, I will have a new character vector with "high" for high Before cholesterol and low for low Before cholesterol. And, then I will do a boxplot of `Difference` based on the categorical new column. So, here is my code. I call the original data set as `df2`.

```
df2 %>% 
  mutate(new_col = if_else(Before < median(Before), "low", "high")) %>%
  group_by(new_col) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x= new_col, y=Difference)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

And following is the boxplot I get
[image]

So, based on this, I conclude that investigators are right and effects of diet on cholesterol are more evident in people with high rather than low cholesterol levels. I want to know if this can be done more effectively.

Comment: This question is likely to generate opinion based answers. Given that the R script in the OP produces a box plot that allows one to answer the question of whether patients with high cholesterol in a pre-test benefit more from a vegetarian diet than patients with low cholesterol in a pre-test, the script is "effective".

Comment: @LenGreski shoudn't it be migrated to stats.stackexchange rather than closed?

Comment: @DanChaltiel - it depends on how one interprets the question. If the question was "is there a more effective way to create a 2 group box plot," I'd say it doesn't need to be migrated. If the question is "is a 2 group comparison the best way to analyze this data?" it merits migration. Maybe user9026 can provide more context, but this looks like a homework question, where a debate about the merits of changing an interval ratio variable to an ordinal variable for analysis is probably beyond what is currently being taught in the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more a statistical plan question rather than a programming question, therefore it would belong more to stats.stackexchange than StackOverflow.

Anyway, categorizing a variable depending on the median is not the recommended way of visualizing associations, as you are suppressing a lot of information. You can read about this in [this very good article](https://medium.com/@peterflom/what-happens-when-we-categorize-an-independent-variable-in-regression-77d4c5862b6c) by Peter Flom.

It is better to keep all the points and apply some spline or smoothing algorithm.

For instance, you could consider something like this:

```
ggplot(df2, aes(x= Before, y=Difference)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth()
```

[image]

Here, the relationship is clearly seeable, while keeping all the information you want.

If you really have to generate subgroups, you could also try something like this:

```
df2 %>% 
  mutate(new_col = if_else(Before < median(Before), "low", "high")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x= Before, y=Difference, group=new_col, color=new_col)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(span=3) #try some other values here
```

However, using the median is still not a very good idea, especially with that amount of data points. You might want to assess the functional form of the relationship, but that would need a specific question on [stats.stackexchange.com](https://stats.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I think that is better. Will check the article, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

not really an answer, but more of a different approach in visualisation of the data..

```
library( data.table )
library( ggplot2 )

DT.melt <- melt( DT, id.vars = "Subject", measure.vars = c( "Before", "After" ) )

ggplot() +
  geom_line( data = DT.melt, 
             aes( x = variable, y = value, group = Subject ) ) +
  geom_line( data = DT.melt[, .(mean = mean(value)), by = variable ],
             aes( x = variable, y = mean, group = 1 ), color = "red", size = 2 ) +
  labs( x = "", y = "" )
```

[image]

**sample data used**

```
DT <- fread(" Subject Before After Difference
        1    195   146         49
        2    145   155        -10
        3    205   178         27
        4    159   146         13
        5    244   208         36
        6    166   147         19
        7    250   202         48
        8    236   215         21
        9    192   184          8
    10    224   208         16
      11    238   206         32
      12    197   169         28
      13    169   182        -13
      14    158   127         31
      15    151   149          2
      16    197   178         19
      17    180   161         19
      18    222   187         35
      19    168   176         -8
      20    168   145         23
      21    167   154         13
      22    161   153          8
      23    178   137         41
      24    137   125         12")
```

Comment: Interesting approach